# Getting the error "Error in : invalid program counter value: 0x00000000 Go: execution terminated with errors. " in MIPS assembly

Tags: mips, computer-science, mips32

I keep getting the error "Error in : invalid program counter value: 0x00000000

Go: execution terminated with errors." when running my program

```
  .data
output: .asciiz "Result: "
    .text
    .globl main

print_int:
    li $v0, 1
    syscall
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, output
    syscall
    jr $ra

Myfun:
    # Prologue
    addi $sp, $sp, -4
    sw $ra, 0($sp)

    # Check if N > 3
    ble $a0, 3, else_case

    # N > 3, calculate Myfun(N-2)
    addi $a0, $a0, -2
    jal Myfun
    move $v0, $v0
    j exit

else_case:
    # N <= 3, return 0
    li $v0, 0
    j exit

exit:
    # Epilogue
    lw $ra, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 4
    jr $ra

main:
    # Prompt user for input
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, output
    syscall

    # Get user input
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    move $a0, $v0

    # Call Myfun(N)
    jal Myfun

    # Print the result
    jal print_int

    # Exit
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Does anyone know why I keep getting this error, and how to fix it? I cant even enter the input value

I tried creating a exit case specific for the else case to reset the stack but I keep getting the same error

Comment: I assume the program will start executing the first instruction and there’s `jr $ra` soon there, which might be the cause.  It doesn’t jump “main”, that should be in the beginning so the execution starts there.

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but there is a bug.  Myfun returns its result in $v0, but print_int expects to print out the value in $a0.  You might also trying to add `.ent main`, so the code knows that's where its supposed to start.

Comment: `move $v0, $v0` is unnecessary.